# Print arglist same way as :ls

Tags: vim

```
:ls
  1  h   "~/Documents/trash/practical-vim" line 1
  3  h   "LICENSE.txt"                  line 1
  4  h   "auto_complete/sea-shells.txt" line 1
  5  h   "files/a.txt"                  line 1
  6  h   "files/b.txt"                  line 1
```

output of ls command, you can use `:b3` to switch to buffer 3, what I want is the same output for `:args` command, but what I get:

```
:args
[auto_complete/webapp/public/index.html] ex_mode/practical-vim.html files/mvc/index.html global/episodes.html
```

i.e. arglist params are printed in one line, which makes usage of `:argument3` (to switch to third file in arglist) basically impossible if amount of files is huge. I want these files to be printed on new line with number by which I can access these files like in `:ls` command.

I tried to write a simple command for this scenario:

```
command! Args 
    \ :let var_args = argv()
    \ :let var_args_size = len(var_args)
    \ :if var_args_size > 0 | let var_args_size = var_args_size - 1 | endif
    \ :for i in range(0, var_args_size) | echo printf("%3d %s", i + 1, var_args[i]) | endfor
```

But:

```
E15: Invalid expression: argv() :let var_args_size = len(var_args) :if var_args_size > 0 | let var_args_size = var_args_size - 1 | endif
 :for i in range(0, var_args_size) | echo printf("%3d %s", i + 1, var_args[i]) | endfor
```

I kindly request assistance either with my command or some other way to print arglist like this:

```
:args
1 auto_complete/webapp/public/index.html
2 ex_mode/practical-vim.html
3 files/mvc/index.html
4 global/episodes.html
```

so i can execute `:argument3` and switch to files/mvc/index.html without counting.

Comment: Try adding `|` at the end of each line (except for the last one) of your `command! Args ...`. Does this work?

Comment: @j1-lee Tried, it worked, thanks, though the way it work is strange, you can write an answer, I ll choose it as a solution.

Comment: No worries, the answer by @Matt seems good---you can accept his/her answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are way beyond the point at which nifty one-liners become liabilities.

Using a function is *much* cleaner:

```
function! Args()
    let var_args = argv()
    let var_args_size = len(var_args)
    if var_args_size > 0
        let var_args_size = var_args_size - 1
    endif
    for i in range(0, var_args_size)
        echo printf("%3d %s", i + 1, var_args[i])
    endfor
endfunction
command! Args call Args()
```

How about a more interactive approach?

```
function! Args()
    let prompt = 'Select an argument:'
    let arg_list = map(argv(), 'v:key + 1 . ". " . v:val')
    let chosen_arg = inputlist([prompt] + arg_list))
    if chosen_arg
        execute 'argument ' . chosen_arg
    endif
endfunction
command! Args call Args()
```

[image: :Args]

See `:help map()`, `:help inputlist()`.

Comment: `All you are doing is echoing a list of things that disappears as soon as you do : to use it.` It does not disappear. That's the point. The same way it works with builtin commands such as `:ls` or `:scriptnames` etc.etc.

Comment: To be more  precise, the output does not disappear if more than `&cmdheight` lines were written (and hence we got in more-prompt). So it works pretty well in most situations.

Comment: Fair enough, I only tried OP's command with one argument.

Comment: I agree function is much cleaner, I just didn't know how to write it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just one line

```
command! -bar Args echo join(map(argv(), {_, v -> printf("%3d\t%s", bufnr(v), v)}), "\n")
```

It shows buffer number instead of argument index, so `:bX` to switch buffer.

Comment: Thanks for solution, but for as for me it is too complex for such simple task.